Can an Election be Modelled with a Binomial Distribution
In my province there was an election recently. In one area the conservative candidate led by 103 votes compared to the progressive candidate. Each received over 8500 votes. The other parties combined got a little more than 1000 votes split between them. There were 634 special votes that were cast before the results came out but were counted a week later. In the end, the progressives won by 27 votes. So out of 634 votes, the majority were given to both parties but the progressives had 130 votes more than the conservatives. I want a model that describes the probability of this event occurring if it is possible. My first thought was to use the binomial distribution with a p = 0.5 as the vote was practically split 50/50 between the two parties and the sample size was quite large. In addition, I felt like I could omit the other parties as they represented only slightly above 5% of the general vote.
So, given there are no external factors, can this be reasonably modelled as binomial distribution where n = 634 and p = 0.5? And if there are other factors which could influence this, say I know some information regarding a demographic that is more likely to case these special ballots, can this be modelled in the same way with maybe a p = 0.7.

This is very dubious, polls can be very inaccurate and special votes can be, as you mention, very unrepresentative, so doing anything of the sort would require big assumptions.

What would be the purpose of the modelling?

I second J-J-J's request for more information. What you could do is to look at the $p$s estimated for the "regular" and the "special" votes, and do a hypothesis test for the null hypothesis that the two $p$s are equal. But again, whether this makes sense depends on what question you are interested in.

The purpose of this modelling would be to see how realistic this outcome is. Just from the regular votes where the sample size is quite large the p value is around 0.5. However, with these special votes the p value has to more than 0.7 for this outcome to be around the expected value. So I see two options. Either I am missing some factors which would indeed increase the p value as said in the example. Or this model is wrong.

The place to start analyzing this question is a survey of the political science literature. I expect it to be deeply considered with many different models and assumptions.

Some computations about elections and the probability of equal outcomes are made in this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451809/ the binomial distribution is one way to compute it, but it assumes a particular variance of the outcome that might not be realistic. A betabinomial distribution might be more correct.
